# Interface in TypeScript's latest version

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

What is interface in TypeScript ?
I tried routing using basic routing method. I learnt that the tutorial I am referring is using an Interface to write the route.
Because I was getting an error when I wrote the same code.
I use webpack to execute my Angular4 code.
I just wanted to know what is Interface and what is it used for and How is it used.
Kindly help

Comment: There is an official documentation... -> [Interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) (first result on google when searching for "typescript interface")

Comment: This too is useful https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_interfaces.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_interfaces.html  is also a good read.
Basically, what I understand about Interface is, it defines properties,methods for the members. And this can be used to reuse the content any number of times.